# How to access different github account on the same laptop

Tags: git, github

I created two different github accounts (one for work another one for research), how can I access any account I like using the same computer?

To explain further, I have been pushing some projects to one of the account without any problem, so I created a new one today (just for research purposes), now when I created a repository in this and tying to connect the local file to the remote one, it cannot find it(which is logical as I didn't login with the new credential).

Please how can I login through different credentials from my windows local computer?

Comment: there is no MPI subroutine in your stack trace ... assuming you declared `char password[6];`, did you initialize `password[5] = '\0';`. For debugging purpose, always build with `-g -Wall`, "silence" all the warnings so you can get a useful stack trace. If still stuck, trim your code down to a [mcve] and edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Gilles, compiling the code with -g -Wall shows that I didn't declare variable password before using it. This fix the error.